# Average child records by month

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

- `sales_header` (contains a `created_at` date)
- `sales_line`

I want to count **the average number of lines on headers per year/month**.

The basic query to get header count per month is easy:

```
SELECT YEAR(h.created_at), MONTH(h.created_at), COUNT(h.id)
FROM   sales_header h
GROUP BY YEAR(h.created_at), MONTH(h.created_at)
ORDER BY YEAR(h.created_at), MONTH(h.created_at);
```

Getting the average lines per header is easy, too:

```
SELECT ROUND(AVG(base.ChildCount), 0)
FROM (
  SELECT li.header_id AS HeaderId, COUNT(li.id) AS ChildCount
  FROM sales_header h
  JOIN sales_line li ON li.header_id = h.id
  GROUP BY li.header_id
) base;
```

I'm just having a hard time putting the two together.

Thanks!

**Update**

Here's some sample data, and a fiddle of same:

```
CREATE TABLE sales_header (
  id INT NOT NULL,
  created_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE sales_line (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  header_id INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (header_id) REFERENCES sales_header(id)
);

INSERT INTO sales_header(id, created_at) VALUES
  (1, '2018-12-31T11:11:11'),
  (2, '2019-01-01T11:11:11'),
  (3, '2019-01-05T11:11:11'),
  (4, '2019-01-10T11:11:11'),
  (5, '2019-01-15T11:11:11'),
  (6, '2019-02-15T11:11:11'),
  (7, '2019-03-01T11:11:11'),
  (8, '2019-03-05T11:11:11'),
  (9, '2019-03-10T11:11:11')
;

INSERT INTO sales_line(header_id) VALUES
  (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1),
  (2), (2), (2), (2),
  (3), (3), (3), (3), (3), 
  (4), (4),
  (5),
  (6), (6), (6), (6), (6), (6),
  (7), (7),
  (8), (8),
  (9), (9), (9), (9), (9), (9), (9), (9), (9), (9), (9), (9), (9)
;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e33a94

What I want to get out is this:

```
| Year | Month | Average Lines Per Header |
| ---- | ----- | ------------------------ |
| 2018 | 12    | 8                        |
| 2019 | 1     | 3                        |
| 2019 | 2     | 6                        |
| 2019 | 3     | 6                        |
```

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: Added.  Sorry, completely slipped my mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the line count to the header table. To get the line count, aggregate sales_line by header_id and count.

```
select year(h.created_at), month(h.created_at), count(*), avg(l.linecount)
from sales_header h
join
(
  select header_id, count(*) as linecount
  from sales_line
  group by header_id
) l on l.header_id = h.id
group by year(h.created_at), month(h.created_at)
order by year(h.created_at), month(h.created_at);
```

Comment: That's actually perfect!  It works (generally) with my sample data set, too.  I just need to add a ROUND in there to get the decimal places out.

Answer (score 0):

Will this work?

```
SELECT
    h.id
    YEAR(h.created_at),
    MONTH(h.created_at),
    COUNT(li.*)
FROM sales_header h
INNER JOIN sales_line li ON li.header_id = h.id
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
ORDER BY h.id
```